# In react-table with React Hooks, how to make a get request inside Cell?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have been working with React-table for a couple of days now, my first time using it, and I have ran into some issues I can't quite seem to resolve. I am trying to build a table where I can show data from two API get requests at the same time, and since I don't know if there is a way to connect the two requests data into one object, and I wouldn't know how to do it, I was trying to access some of the data with get requests inside the react-table Column Cell itself.

My case being: I have two objects, Contacts and Institutions, contacts have in their data the institution ID as parameter, and I need to show in the table both the contact information and some information of the institution that is linked to it, getting it from the institution ID that is present in the contact data.

Here is one example of contact:

```
{
   "contact_id": "34378a25-fe8c-4c64-bd35-59eab3f30863",
   "institution_id": "ae1d0fe8-cce1-40ef-87d7-729dfbe9716d",
   "name": "Contato 2",
   "role": "Cargo 1",
   "phone_numbers": [],
   "emails": [],
   "createdAt": "2021-03-09T20:40:26.6863764Z",
   "updatedAt": "2021-03-09T20:40:26.686376448Z",
   "deleted": false
}
```

And here is the institution data:

```
{
 "institution_id": "ae1d0fe8-cce1-40ef-87d7-729dfbe9716d",
  "name": "Matheus Salles Blanco",
  "socialReason": "teste",
  "cnpj": "99999999999999",
  "abbreviation": "Matheus",
  "website": "teste.com",
}
```

This is the code that is being implemented, reduced to only the parts that matter and that is working, but only showing the info that is being fetched from the contact object:

```
const Contacts = ({ match }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [institution, setInstitution] = useState();
  const dataRecoil = useRecoilValue(contactData);

  const handleContact = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = dataRecoil.data;
    if (response) {
      setData(response.filter((contact) => !contact.deleted));
    }
  }, [setData, dataRecoil]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleContact();
  }, [handleContact]);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Nome',
        accessor: 'name',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Sigla',
        accessor: 'abbreviation',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Nome Fantasia',
        accessor: 'institution_id',
      },
    ],
    [editToggle, handleDelete],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```

And a print of it:
[image: Working code]

And here is what I have been trying to do:

```
const Contacts = ({ match }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [institution, setInstitution] = useState();
  const dataRecoil = useRecoilValue(contactData);

  const handleContact = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = dataRecoil.data;
    if (response) {
      setData(response.filter((contact) => !contact.deleted));
    }
  }, [setData, dataRecoil]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleContact();
  }, [handleContact]);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Nome',
        accessor: 'name',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Sigla',
        accessor: 'abbreviation',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Nome Fantasia',
        accessor: 'institution_id',
        Cell: async ({ cell }) => {
          const response = await getInstitutionById(cell.row.values.institution_id);
          const result = [response.data];
          const inst = result.map((inst) => {return inst.name});
          const institution_name = inst[0];
          console.log(institution_name);
          return institution_name;
        },
      },
    ],
    [editToggle, handleDelete],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Which works at the level of fetching the right data, but does not render the page and shows errors:

[image: The error]
The error

[image: The right data being shown]
The right data being shown in the console.log

The expected output would be to show those names on the console.log on place of that long ID of the first picture.

So, is it possible to do what I am trying to do? And if so, what might am I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are providing an async function for your cell, which will return a `Promise`, not the institution name as you are expecting.

A potential solution is to instead create a custom Cell component that uses state to store the institution name. I have provided an example below, which was guided by [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5n96yvwnm), however I have not tested the code at all, so use it as more of a guide.

```js
const MyCell = ({ cell }) => {

  const [institutionName, setInstitutionName] = useState('fetching...')

  useEffect(() => {
    const getInstitutionName = async (id) => {
      const response = await getInstitutionById(id);
      const result = [response.data];
      const inst = result.map((inst) => {return inst.name});
      const institution_name = inst[0];
      console.log(institution_name);
      setInstitutionName(institution_name)
    }

    getInstitutionName(cell.row.values.institution_id)
  }

  return institutionName
}

const Contacts = ({ match }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [institution, setInstitution] = useState();
  const dataRecoil = useRecoilValue(contactData);

  const handleContact = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = dataRecoil.data;
    if (response) {
      setData(response.filter((contact) => !contact.deleted));
    }
  }, [setData, dataRecoil]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleContact();
  }, [handleContact]);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Nome',
        accessor: 'name',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Sigla',
        accessor: 'abbreviation',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Nome Fantasia',
        accessor: 'institution_id',
        Cell: MyCell
      },
    ],
    [editToggle, handleDelete],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: glad i could help!